# Is "by all means" in this sentence a correct usage? How to express "I can be reached in any way"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

I've recently noticed that some of my colleagues(mostly non-native English speakers) write this in emails:

> I will work from XXX today. I can be reached **by all means**.

What they mean is they can be reached in any possible way. But does `by all means` imply `by doing whatever is necessary`? It sounds a bit too strong to use `by all means` in the above quotes.

What is the idiomatic way of expressing `I can be reached in any possible way`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**By all means** is a very idiomatic phrase that doesn't really mean what you're looking for, so I wouldn't use it that way.

[**By all means** idiomatically means "certainly" or "definitely."](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/by-all-means)  You would use it like this:

> "Can we go visit Talia today?"
>   "By all means!  I'll call her and let her know we're coming."

The idiomatic sense is so strong it doesn't really make sense to use the phrase in any other way.

A more fluent way to say "in any possible way" might be to use the word **any**, just as you did in your explanation.  *All* has an implication of "every", whereas *any* just means "any single one".

> I can be reached by any means

although [by any means](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/by--any--means) also has some idiomatic meaning.  It might be better to use the word *method*:

> I can by reached by any method

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that anyone can *certainly* contact you, without hesitation or doubt. Check [Collins and phrase's meanings on the page.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/by-all-means)

It's not *strong,* it's just a way to tell that though you are working from *any place,* you are traceable and anyone can contact you if they want to.

Comment: It means *certainly*, but it does not mean what the OP was asking about which was "in any possible way".